# How to change FK Name in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am wondering how do I change the name of a FK with fluent nhibernate.

Right now it makes all the foreign keys like (product_id,student_id) what is find but there is one table I want it to have a different name.

I want the courses table to have for the foreign key "MyFKName" but it keeps generating "student_id"

```
 public CourseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Student).ForeignKey("MyFKName");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are probably looking for is

```
public CourseMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    References(x => x.Student).KeyColumn("MyFKName");
}
```

`ForeignKey` is the name of the foreign key constraint

Comment: I tired that too but it seems to put 2 columns for my FK. It would put "student_id" & "MyFKName" seems like on the Student Mapping for the hasMany I need to put "MyFKName" as a column name. It make it only have 1 column.

Comment: @chobo2 yes they are 2 different relations an one-to-many and a Man-to-one. when they should share the foreignkey column you have to specify it in both mappings